# How to prevent container in itemRenderer from exceeding width of list container?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, layout, mxml, itemrenderer

In a Flex Mobile project I have a simple itemRenderer where I'm trying to create an "bubble" texting effect, similar to ichat or iphone (just so you get what im going for). But if the text is longer than the screen it runs off, rather than just going down a line.

If I set Group thats holding the rectangle(to create the bubble effect) and the label to 100% it works and keeps it from exceeding the list containers bounds, BUT the group is always at 100% and looks bad, I'm trying to keep the "bubble" JUST AROUND the text.

Anyway so, at the top of my itemRenderer I tried specifying:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="100%" height="100%">
```

And here's my layout I figured since `msg_container` has a width of 100% I was hoping `bubble_lable_group` would just not exceed that but...it doesnt...it just runs off. I tried setting a max width but that does not allow you to input percents. And just to say it 1 more time. I know if i set `bubble_lable_group` width to 100% it works, and keeps it from going off the edge, but then the rectangle "bubble" stretches all the way across and just looks bad.

```
<s:VGroup id="main_container" horizontalAlign="left" paddingBottom="10" paddingTop="10"
              verticalAlign="top" width="100%">

        <s:VGroup id="name_container" width="100%">
            <s:Label id="name_label" fontSize="20" fontWeight="bold" text="Name: " />
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup id="msg_container" width="100%" paddingLeft="20">
            <s:Group id="bubble_lable_group">
                <s:Rect id="the_bubble_shape" width="100%" height="100%" radiusX="15" radiusY="15" >
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="{grOne}"/>
                            <s:GradientEntry color="{grTwo}"/>
                        </s:LinearGradient>
                    </s:fill>
                </s:Rect>
                <s:Label id="msg_txt" width="100%" text="msg text here"
                         fontSize="18" color="#FFFFFF" paddingTop="15" paddingRight="15" paddingBottom="15" paddingLeft="15"/>
            </s:Group>
        </s:VGroup>

    </s:VGroup>
```

Any Ideas or tricks I could pull to achieve the effect i'm going for and keep it all inside the parent List container? I'm stumped.

EDIT:
Here's some screenshots to help illustrate the issue:
[image][image]

Comment: Does your List set variableRowHeight to true?  Screenshots may help and/or a full runnable sample.

Comment: I added some screenshots to help illustrate the problem. I dont think spark Mobile lists have variableRowHeight it doesn't seem to exist. But as you can see in the second screenshot it adjusts the height when the width is set to 100%. I just dont understand why bubble_lable_group exceeds msg_container. I guess since im not specifying anything it just thinks it can run on.

Comment: In Spark you set the variableRowHeight on the layout class; not the actual list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it looks like you want to set the `maxWidth` property.  Only, you can only set that with pixels, not percents.  I am guessing that since you are on mobile, you don't want to be setting absolute pixels.  Soooo, what if you did something a bit tricky?  Data bind the max width to be the width of the renderer minus the padding of your message container...

```
<s:Group id="bubble_lable_group" maxWidth="{width - msg_container.paddingLeft}" >
```

Feels like a hack, but it works for me :)

**NOTE:** Using the standard `ItemRenderer` class is quite inefficient in Mobile.  It may not be an issue for you, but just be aware of it.  See this presentation from 360Flex for more info on that: http://zaa.tv/2011/06/360flex-denver-2011-flex-performance-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: Hmm, well it works! so Thanks! ...But it's giving me some warnings,  `Multiple markers at this line:
-Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to 
 "paddingLeft"` I'm not exactly sure why this works..I tried `{width - msg_container.width}` and  just `{msg_container.paddingLeft}` but neither of those worked. Do you really think this is the only way to do this? Those warnings will irritate the crap out of me. And about the ItemRenderer class is there even another option? I know about IconItem renderer but I dont think you can customize it the way i'm doing.

Comment: You get that error because `paddingLeft` is not `[Bindable]`.  The initial bind works, but updates to that variable do not.  That is what the warning tells you.  Not a problem in this case because `paddingLeft` does not change.  There might be a better way to do it... but this is the one I came up with :)  `ItemRenderer`, `IconItemRenderer`, AS-Only go easiest to hardest but slowest to fastest.  You CAN get this working with `IconItemRenderer` or AS-Only renderers... it is just more difficult.

Comment: To fix the warning, either have another Group between bubble_label_group and it's parent who's width is 100% and the top one has the padding, so that the internal group just binds to the width of the one above (without the need of padding).  Either that or use the creation complete event to set it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a different question, but this might be helpful to clipAndEnableScrolling="true"